# Uninstall Adobe Creative Cloud (CC) from macOS Catalina when uninstaller is 32-bit

Tags: catalina, macos, adobe, adobe-photoshop

I've upgraded to macOS Catalina and now noticing some long unused apps that I'm purging from my system.  Adobe Creative Cloud being one of them (well, many of them).

I know there is an Creative Cloud Uninstaller but it is 32-bit so won't run on Catalina. I've downloaded the most recent but after running it quits with errors (and doesn't seem to do a thing).

Is there a list of every CC file that Adobe spewed throughout my filesystem so I can delete them manually?

Comment: Have you tried the [Adobe Creative Cloud Cleaner Tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/cc-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html#run_cc_cleaner_tool_for_mac)?  The KB shows it was just updated so maybe it can help.  I'm not adding this as an answer because I don't know if it will work for you or not.

Comment: @fsb unfortunately that didn't work. It may have done something (hard to tell) but it didn't clear 32-bit apps from `/Applications` or from `/System/Application Support/Adobe` or elsewhere in `Preferences` as I was hoping.

Comment: This is something you need to ask Adobe about directly.

Answer (score 2):

**Fully removing Creative Cloud**

Basically, you need to look for files in the following folders:

```
 /Library/Application Support/Adobe
~/Library/Application Support/Adobe
 /Library/LaunchAgents
~/Library/LaunchAgents
~/Library/Preferences
```

However, removing CC without breaking other Adobe apps is kinda challenge...

**The conservative way**

If CC annoys you but you have the space for it (a couple of MB) and you are not willing risking to destroy your Adobe environment. I would recommend to simply disable it from being loaded at boot. To do so:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AdobeCreativeCloud.plist
```

To be sure it is done, redoing the command above should return:

```
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AdobeCreativeCloud.plist: Could not find specified service
```